# Javascript calling class function from initated class

Tags: javascript

I can call class function from initiated class, but i cant display value of class property.

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.myvariable = "value";
    let b = new B(this.myCallback);
  }

  myCallback() {
    console.log(`myCallback() => ${this.myvariable}`);
  }
}

class B {
  constructor(cb) {
    cb();
  }
}

var a = new A();
```

I need to call `class A` method from `class B`. When I do as above, console prints `this.myvariable` as undefined.

Answer (score 3):

That is happening as the `myCallback` is losing its context, you need to bind the `myCallback` to the context of the `class A` instance explicitly.

Without the context inside `myCallback`, `this.myvariable` would be undefined:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.myvariable = "value";
    let b = new B(this.myCallback.bind(this));
  }

  myCallback() {
    console.log(`myCallback() => ${this.myvariable}`);
  }
}

class B {
  constructor(cb) {
    cb();
  }
}

var a = new A();
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer has explained what is really happening clearly, here just provide an alternative to achieve that, since *Arrow functions do not bind their own this, instead, they inherit the one from the parent scope*, we can also do it like so:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.myvariable = "value";
    let b = new B(this.myCallback);
  }

  myCallback = () => {
    console.log(`myCallback() => ${this.myvariable}`);
  }
}

class B {
  constructor(cb) {
    cb();
  }
}

var a = new A();
```

but using arrow function as class member is an experimental feature, so for better compatibility:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.myvariable = "value";
    let b = new B(() => this.myCallback());
  }

  myCallback(){
    console.log(`myCallback() => ${this.myvariable}`);
  }
}

class B {
  constructor(cb) {
    cb();
  }
}

var a = new A();
```